# My program decodes a QR code standalone but when I integrate it into Tkinter GUI, it does not

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

using a web camera and the pyzbar library, I am trying to recognize the contents of the QR code, the web camera sees the QR code, but recognition does not occur, please help me figure it out, below is the code

```
def qr_webcam_reader():
ret, frame = capture.read()
if ret:
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 280))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    LabelCamera.imgtk = imgtk
    LabelCamera.configure(image=imgtk)
for code in decode(frame):
    decoded_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
    rect_pts = code.rect

    if decoded_data:
        pts = np.array([code.polygon], np.int32)
        cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(frame, str(decoded_data), (rect_pts[0], rect_pts[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
win.after(10, qr_webcam_reader)
```

the code below works, but it is important for me to do it with tkinter and read the code in the label after putting it in the database

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, frame = cap.read()

    if not success:
        break

    for code in decode(frame):
        decoded_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
        rect_pts = code.rect

        if decoded_data:
            pts = np.array([code.polygon], np.int32)
            cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 3)
            cv2.putText(frame, str(decoded_data), (rect_pts[0], rect_pts[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)


    cv2.imshow("camera", frame)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
cap.release()
```

Comment: [mre] requires input data. dump a video frame and provide it as input.

Comment: I'm new to python, if you understand opencv could you answer in more detail

Comment: `cv2.imwrite("frame.png", frame)` and provide this file with your question

Comment: ah, so your issue isn't pyzbar or opencv but ***Tkinter***! please present a [mre]

Comment: yes, the problem is in tkinter itself, pyzabar is not implemented with tkinter

Comment: Your standalone code is decoding the image directly; the tkinter code is resizing it first.  Perhaps the resized image is simply not high enough resolution for the QR code to be recognized?

Comment: You should do the tasks in this order: resize frame, decode frame, convert frame to PIL image and then display it.

Comment: @acw1668 can you show a demo, at the moment you have not figured out how to do it?

Comment: you should run `img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`  (and rest) at the end of function `qr_webcam_reader` - similar to `cv2.imshow("camera", frame)` at the end of original code.

Comment: @furas for some reason, when searching, it captures a frame and hangs on it, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the tasks in this order:

- resize the captured frame
- decode the resized frame
- convert the frame to PIL image
- show the image

```py
def qr_webcam_reader():
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if ret:
        # resize frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 280))
        # decode frame
        for code in decode(frame):
            decoded_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
            if decoded_data:
                rect_pts = code.rect
                pts = np.array([code.polygon], np.int32)
                cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 3)
                cv2.putText(frame, str(decoded_data), (rect_pts[0], rect_pts[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # convert the frame to PILL image
        img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = Image.fromarray(img)
        # show the image
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        LabelCamera.imgtk = imgtk
        LabelCamera.configure(image=imgtk)

    win.after(10, qr_webcam_reader)
```

Comment: thank you very much, does it really work, if i want to pass the received value to tkinter.label or tkinter.entry should i put it inside the functions ?

Comment: Do you mean the `decoded_data`? If yes, you can put it in `LabelCamera` as well like `LabelCamera.configure(image=imgtk, text=str(decoded_data), compound="top")`.

Comment: It's good, it's works, If I want to enter this data into the database, what would be the best way? Through Label or there are other methods? thank you very much you helped a lot!

Comment: @mark I suggest you to raise a new question.

Comment: ok Thank's very much!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but I think you should add image to `Label` at the end of function `qr_webcam_reader()` - similar to `cv.imshow()` at the end of loop `while True` in original code.

```
def qr_webcam_reader():

    success, frame = capture.read()
    
    if not success:
        return       # `return` instead of `break`
    
    for code in decode(frame):
        decoded_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
        rect_pts = code.rect

        if decoded_data:
            pts = np.array([code.polygon], np.int32)
            cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 3)
            cv2.putText(frame, str(decoded_data), (rect_pts[0], rect_pts[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            
    # instead of `cv.imshow()`
                
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 280))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    LabelCamera.imgtk = imgtk
    LabelCamera.configure(image=imgtk)
            
# ---
            
win.after(10, qr_webcam_reader)
```